# How do I get integrity error to continue inserting into db -- python?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, peewee

I have a postgres DB that looks like this:

```
                                                        Table "public.available_dates"
   Column   |            Type             |                          Modifiers                           | Storage | Stats target | Description
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('available_dates_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 unix_day   | integer                     |                                                              | plain   |              |
 hour       | integer                     |                                                              | plain   |              |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                              | plain   |              |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                              | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "available_dates_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_available_dates_on_unix_day_and_hour" UNIQUE, btree (unix_day, hour)
    "index_available_dates_on_unix_day" btree (unix_day)
Has OIDs: no
```

This is hooked into a rails app I'm developing and a python app that runs as a service, I use peewee as the orm for python. The rails app runs fine, and I need each of the indexes on this db.

The python application looks at files, and adds dates to the db. The problem I am having is if the date+hour exists, it fails and ends the python app. I don't want dupes in the db, but I also want the app to continue running if this integrity error is thrown. This is the code I have so far:

```
data_source = [{'unix_day': 1370044800, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 14, 10, 12, 57, 488000), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 14, 10, 12, 57, 488000), 'hour': 1}, 
...
]

        try:
            with db.transaction():
                Available_Dates.insert_many(data_source).execute()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print e
            db.rollback()
            pass
        else:
            db.commit()
        db.close()
```

Which fails (as it should):

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_available_dates_on_unix_day_and_hour"
    DETAIL:  Key (unix_day, hour)=(1370044800, 10) already exists.

**How do I get my code to say, "That failed? Oh well... I just try the next one."**

Note: I expect it will fail more than it will succeed.

Edit: Option 1 as per first answer:

```
for data in data_source:
            try:
                av_date = Available_Dates()
                av_date.unix_day = data['unix_day']
                av_date.hour = data['hour']
                av_date.created_at = data['created_at']
                av_date.updated_at = data['updated_at']
                av_date.save()

            except Exception as e:
                pass
```

This seems not great as I'm catching all exceptions... Also, I have to assign every member separately which seems inefficient. It also fails because there is a lock on the db.

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_available_dates_on_unix_day_and_hour"
DETAIL:  Key (unix_day, hour)=(1370044800, 1) already exists.

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
 ...
```

Comment: It looks like you are catching the wrong exception, look up what error you should really catch(if your except line just says except Exception, e: it will run fine, but it is bad form because it will mask errors).  Also why not do a check in the table to see if that record already exists first?

Comment: Options I see are to insert everything and get rid of my unique constraint and just clean up dupes later; do many inserts rather than a transaction;

Comment: That sounds slow and prone to error - bad option.  Keep the try catch block after modifying to properly catch error.  If you want to do bulk inserts you can use pandas or sets to check if it is already in your table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I did (thanks to ZJS):

```
for data in data_source:
            try:
                exists = Available_Dates.get(Available_Dates.unix_day == data['unix_day'],
                                             Available_Dates.hour == data['hour'])
            except Available_Dates.DoesNotExist:
                av_date = Available_Dates.create(**data)
                print av_date.id, "added to the database."
            except Exception as e:
                print e, type(e)
                pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this, in case it's useful

```
data = [(a,b), (a,b), (a,b)]

with database.atomic():
    # try bulk
    try:
        MyModel.insert_many(data, fields=[MyModel.field1, MyModel.field2]).execute()
    # if it fails, switch to individually adding (slower)
    except IntegrityError:
        for d in data:
            try:
                entry = MyModel(
                    field1=d[0],
                    field2=d[1],)
                entry.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you insert everything with a single function, `insert_many` in this case, that's going to make it more difficult to continue in the face of an exception. My suggestion would be to insert each item one at a time, in a `for` loop, and wrap each individual insert in a `try-except` instead of the whole thing.